# Custom Shell Prompt for Root per sudo/su user

Tags: prompt

Is it possible to have multiple users using a root shell but with different prompts on the BASH shell for each session/user? We have some training environments with our users using su/sudo to get to a root shell for demonstration purposes.

**Note: I'm aware of best practice regarding su/sudo etc. These are training environments and I specifically want then to run an interactive shell as root for learning purposes.**

Comment: For training purposes, you may want them to have individual user accounts (with their username in the prompt) from which they use `sudo` to prefix administrational commands without ever getting an interactive root prompt, _in their own personal VM_ set up for the training session. For training purposes, that would _definitely_ be best.  For hacked up systems were things can be expected to work very differently from anywhere else, the root prompt can probably be made to contain the value of the `SUDO_USER` variable. I leave it up to other users here to write that up as an answer.

Comment: All the training users do have a standard shell with their username in the prompt. I then get them to do something like `sudo -s`, `sudo -i`  or `su -` to get a shell as root. I do specifically want them to run the interactive shell as root. I want this to demonstrate various aspects as to why we don't generally do this in production.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by playing with `who`. It can give you a real user name.

For example, adding into `/root/.bashrc` the code like

```
REALUSER=`who -m|cut -f1 -d' '`
export PS1="$REALUSER->\u \$ "
```

Comment: You don't have to `export` the `PS1` variable, or any other variables that child processes never have to see.  Also note the missing backtick, and that `who -m` will not work on systems such as Alpine Linux (using busybox `who`).

Comment: Very good point! I also read the man page (which I should have done more thoroughly see `sudo -E` is an option that preserves the callers environment